# Different ways to avoid deadlocks

Tags: operating-systems, deadlocks

I am thinking of techniques that we can implement in order to avoid deadlocks in processes. While I am aware of some tactics, e.g. killing a process when we reach a deadlock, or using spooling, would there be any other viable solutions?

For example, can we adjust a process to be executed if it is urgent, and has higher priority for execution, or maybe execute a process which asks for the smallest amount of resources? Or even, depending on the resource, we remove it from a process which has reached a deadlock and then re-use it by giving it again to the processes?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Prevention) has some suggestions.

Comment: Also look at [priority ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_ceiling_protocol) and [priority inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inheritance). The overarching topic you're looking for is likely [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing))